# Automatic python code formatting in sublime

Tags: python, sublimetext

I am trying to find some package that would auto format python code when using sublime.

There is PythonTidy, but when I use PackageController it says install completed but the package is not installed (does not appear in preferences).

I did try following the instructions in:
https://github.com/witsch/SublimePythonTidy

and while i "pip installed" the package in python, sublime would not load, throwing:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::python::error_already_set'
/usr/bin/subl: line 3: 12415 Aborted                 
/usr/lib/sublime-text-2/sublime_text --class=sublime-text-2 "$@"
```

How would I go about installing this without PackageController, or alternatively, can anyone recommend another package?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try doing the following in command line (a bit brute force):

1. Navigate into the `Packages/PythonTidy` folder,
   usually `~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/PythonTidy`
   or `~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/SublimePythonTidy`

   - If it's non-existent reinstalling using `Package Control`
2. Inside there should be another `PythonTidy` folder (which in your case will be empty).
   **Don't get into it, just check it is empty**.
3. Run `git clone https://github.com/witsch/PythonTidy.git`
4. Restart sublime and check the console for errors (`View` -> `Show Console`)

**P.S.**
If you are unable to start `Sublime` do a:

```
sudo pip uninstall PythonTidy
```

Then retry what I wrote above.

Answer (score 14):

ctrl+shift+P  then Package Control: Install Package
Look for `Python PEP8 Autoformat` and install it.

Comment: after installing the package you can format your code by pressing: Ctrl+Shift+R

Comment: Ctrl+shift+r is giving me an option for navigating into methods in the class

Comment: Unfortunately, this plugin's BitBucket repo now [returns a 404](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Python%20PEP8%20Autoformat), so you cannot install this plugin via Package Control at this time. There are several forks on GitHub and BitBucket, but you'll have to install it manually. Here's one: https://github.com/gsemet/pythonpep8autoformat

Answer (score 1):

Package Control should create an appropriately named folder in Sublime Text's packages folder.  You can get there from `Preferences > Browse Packages`.  If the package installed correctly, there should be a folder called PythonTidy.  If there's not, you can download the package from github directly and place the folder in this Packages folder.